# How to get another class variable value only when it changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I am trying to get the value (only when it changes from null to some value) of a synchronous variable value exist in another class. i am able to get the value by using the code below but i know this is wrong way as i can't be using the resources until i get a return value.

```
   private string responseText;
   responseText= request.SyncronousResponse;
   while (true)
        {
            if (responseText == null)
            {
                responseText = request.SyncronousResponse;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
```

What is the best way to get this request.SyncronousResponse value without looping.

Comment: what is a `synchronous variable`? Well I can guess from your code but the answer (this is ASP.NET right?) is either use async. calls to fetch the response or respond with an error yourself if it is not ready - don't delay calls like this - this will blow up your CPU with useless work and is the opposite of scalable

Comment: @CarstenKönig Yes thats right ASP.NET. How do i use async variable

Comment: not a *variable*  - you should either use a async-function to fetch your `responseText` or just compute it synchronously on the spot - but don't use a field in the back to synchronize threads or something like this

Comment: and if you really must use a [`TaskCompletionSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx) (that can be awaited) or a [`Lazy-Field`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) if you don't really want to wait but only compute something once (like here)

Comment: @CarstenKönig i cant use the async-function as i cant change that existing class code.